# Merging multiple workbooks in to one workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to take multiple Excel workbooks (that each have 1 worksheet) and merge them in to one Workbook.

So currently I have 9 workbooks, each with 1 worksheet, I would like to end up with 1 workbook, with 9 worksheets.

This is the code I have been using:

```
Function MergeBooks(Path As String)
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    With NewBook
        .Title = "Merged Data"
        .Subject = "End User Data"
        .SaveAs Filename:=Path & "mergedFinal.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

    End With

    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            Sheet.Copy After:=NewBook.Sheets(1)
        Next Sheet

    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    NewBook.Save
End Function
```

In my mind it seems to follow the right steps, I plan to run this from PowerShell and so far it runs and makes the new file, and I can see it loop through the files in the folder, so these are being picked up fine. However, when going to copy the worksheet on line 15 it produces an error "out of memory". The final product workbook then ends up empty.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think the quickest answer based on what I'm seeing is clear the variables and clipboard after each run. E.g. `set objects = Nothing` and call `Application.CutCopyMode = False` to clear the clipboard. Longer term, try avoiding using the clipboard altogether and just write a Range Object to another equally sized Range Object.

Comment: I think having the ".SaveAs" at the beginning was confusing the activesheet, so I moved it to happen last once the work is done. That combined with the "Application.CutCopyMode = False" it now works. Thank you for your help